# manipulating array to use in different contex

Tags: php, arrays, regex

I am using regex to match pattern. Then pushing matched result using `pushToResultSet`. In both way of doing, would `$resultSet` have similar array content? Similar means not 
insense of value, but format. I want to use 2nd way in alternative to 1st code.

**UPDATE**: Example with sample input http://ideone.com/lIaP49

```
foreach ($words as $word){
    $pattern = '/^(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
    $this->pushToResultSet($matches);
} 
return $resultSet;
```

Now I am doing this in another way and pushing array in similar way. As `$matches` is array and here `$b` is also array, I guess both code are similar

```
$b = array();
$pattern = '/^(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
foreach ($test as $value)
{
    $value = strtolower($value);
    // Capture also the numbers so we just concat later, no more string substitution.
    $matches = preg_split('/(\d+)/', $value, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    if ($matches)
    {
        $newValue = array();
        foreach ($matches as $word)
        {
            // Replace if a valid word number.
            $newValue[] = (isset($arrwords[$word]) ? $arrwords[$word] : $word);
        }
        $newValue = implode($newValue);            
        if (preg_match($pattern, $newValue))
        {
                $b[] = $value;  
            $this->pushToResultSet($b);
        }
    }
}       
//print_r($b);
return $resultSet;
```

**UPDATE**
ACtual code which I want to replace out with 2nd code in the question:

```
<?php
class Phone extends Filter{
    function parse($text, $words)
    {   
        $arrwords = array(0=>'zero',1=>'one',2=>'two',3=>'three',4=>'four',5=>'five',6=>'six',7=>'seven',8=>'eight',9=>'nine');
        preg_match_all('/[A-za-z]+/', $text, $matches);
        $arr=$matches[0];
        foreach($arr as $v)
        {
            $v = strtolower($v);
            if(in_array($v,$arrwords))
            {
            $text= str_replace($v,array_search($v,$arrwords),$text);
            }
        }
        //$resultSet = array();
        $l = strlen($text);
        foreach ($words as $word){
            $pattern = '/^(?:\((\+?\d+)?\)|(\+\d{0,3}))? ?\d{2,3}([-\.]?\d{2,3} ?){3,4}/';
            preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
            //print_r($matches);
        }
        //print_r($matches);
        $this->pushToResultSet($matches);
        return $resultSet;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your link doesn't show the error you described under my answer.  Also, I see no reference to `pushToResultSet` in that code either.

Comment: @merlin2011: yes, ideone contains just piece of code to show input and output result. Actual code that I want to replace is I have updated in question at the bottom

Comment: Please add a second ideone link which exhibits the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

After running both codes, run PHP's [`var_dump`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.var-dump.php) function on the output variables.

If the printed output matches for your definition of *similar array content*, then your answer is **yes**. Otherwise, your answer is **no**.

Comment: can you please tell me in 2nd code, `$this->pushToResultSet($b);
` pushed to which variable?

Comment: When I did `print_r($resultSet);` it gaver error syntex error `Array ^`

Comment: @cyclic, I suggested `var_dump`, not `print_r`.

Comment: @cyclic, I am not familiar with that function and nor was I able to find any documentation on it. Is that a standard PHP function? If so, you should be able to find the documentation on it and that should tell you which variable it pushes to.

Comment: @cyclic, Please provide some sample input to make the problem fully reproducible.

Comment: thanks for giving time. I have given ideone example with sample input and output